# Weird compilation error when using switch on enumeration

Tags: java, compiler-errors, switch-statement

I just noticed one curious case and wanted to see if someone will be able to explain it. Here is my case:

```
private enum Classifiers {
    NEURAL_NETWORK, NEAREST_NEIGHBOURS, IDENTITY;
}
private ClassifierInterface getClassifierInstance(Classifiers classifier) {
    switch (classifier) {
    case NEURAL_NETWORK:
        return new DoubleLayeredNeuralNetwork();
    case NEAREST_NEIGHBOURS:
        return new NearestNeighbours();
    case IDENTITY:
        return new IdentityClassifier();
    }
    return null; // If I comment out this line I get compilation error
}
```

See the comment. I would expect that `Unreachable code` error will be reported for this line. Instead I get `Method must return value` error if I comment out this line. However, there is no way the program flow will pass through there.

I even assumed it would be a guard case for the case of `null` value passed-in, but as expected this triggers `NullPointerException` for the switch condition.

I do not use `switch` very often, probably I am missing something here. Can somebody please try to help understand this behaviour?

Comment: I always wondered too why the compiler isn't smart enough to see that it returns always something and the `return null` is redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct behaviour as you do not have a default case statement.  The problem is that you could add an value to the `enum` later and not re-compile the code which uses it.  By forcing you to always handle when it is not one of the values, this is covered.

BTW: `classifier` could be null which is another option switch doesn't handle unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However your BTW not is not quite so, I already mentioned it in my question : null value triggers NPE in the switch.

Comment: My point was; I would have liked switch to support `case null:` or treat `null` as a `default:`

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 3):

That question is interesting...

We have something like this and the compiler is happy!

```
public enum Coin {
     PENNY,
     NICKEL,
     DIME,
     QUARTER;
}

private enum CoinColor { COPPER, NICKEL, SILVER }
private static CoinColor color(Coin c) {
    switch(c) {
        case PENNY:
            return CoinColor.COPPER;
        case NICKEL:
            return CoinColor.NICKEL;
        case DIME: case QUARTER:
            return CoinColor.SILVER;
        default:
            throw new AssertionError("Unknown coin: " + c);
    }
}
```

The Java Languaje Specification says:

> A Java compiler is encouraged (but not required) to provide a warning
>   if a switch on an enum-valued expression lacks a default label and
>   lacks case labels for one or more of the enum type's constants. (Such
>   a statement will silently do nothing if the expression evaluates to
>   one of the missing constants.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Especially for the quote. However, a warning is mentioned there, whilst I get a compilation error. Interesting. Your example is good too.